# Python - IntVar/entry in tkinter will only return 0

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to write a program to do calculations and solve equations, using a gui made with tkinter, and have gotten to the point of putting in known values. The values are entered in tkinter's entry widget(I am using IntVar(), not StringVar(), so that's not the problem), but for some reason, no matter the value I enter, it will only return as 0. code below:

```
def getvalues_1dk():
    getvalues2frame = ttk.Frame(calculations_root, width=100, height=100, padding="5")
    getvalues2frame['borderwidth'] = 3
    getvalues2frame['relief'] = 'raised'
    getvalues2label = ttk.Label(getvalues2frame, text="Step 5: Enter a value for each of the variables you\n"
                                                      " selected in step 4.")
    getvalues2label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=(N, W))
    getvalues2frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
    getvalue1(getvalues2frame)
    return getvalues2frame

def getvalue1(getvalues2frame):
    if known1d1.get() and known1d2.get() and known1d3.get():
        known1d1entryvar = IntVar()
        known1d1entry = ttk.Entry(getvalues2frame, textvariable=known1d1entryvar)
        ttk.Label(getvalues2frame, text=known1d1.get()).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        known1d1entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)
        ttk.Button(getvalues2frame, text="Confirm",
                   command=(getvalue2(getvalues2frame, known1d1entryvar))).grid(row=3, column=1,
                                                                                sticky=E)
        return known1d1entryvar

def getvalue2(getvalues2frame, known1d1entryvar):
    if known1d1entryvar.get():
        known1d2entryvar = IntVar()
        known1d2entry = ttk.Entry(getvalues2frame, textvariable=known1d2entryvar)
        ttk.Label(getvalues2frame, text=known1d2.get()).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        known1d2entry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E)
        ttk.Button(getvalues2frame, text="Confirm",
                   command=(getvalue3(getvalues2frame, known1d1entryvar, known1d2entryvar))).grid(row=5, column=1,
                                                                                                  sticky=E)
        return known1d2entryvar

def getvalue3(getvalues2frame, known1d1entryvar, known1d2entryvar):
    if known1d2entryvar.get():
        known1d3entryvar = IntVar()
        known1d3entry = ttk.Entry(getvalues2frame, textvariable=known1d3entryvar)
        ttk.Label(getvalues2frame, text=known1d3.get()).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
        known1d3entry.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)
        calculatebutton = ttk.Button(getvalues2frame, text="Show formula and calculate",
                                     command=(
                                         calculate1d(known1d1entryvar, known1d2entryvar, known1d3entryvar,
                                                     solveforvar1d, unusedvar1d)))
        calculatebutton.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=E)

def calculate1d(known1d1entryvar, known1d2entryvar, known1d3entryvar, solveforvar1d, unusedvar1d):
    if known1d1entryvar.get() and known1d2entryvar.get() and known1d3entryvar.get():
        knownvar1 = known1d1entryvar.get()
        knownvar2 = known1d2entryvar.get()
        knownvar3 = known1d3entryvar.get()
        print(knownvar1, knownvar2, knownvar3)
        solveforvar1d = Symbol(solveforvar1d)
        print(solveforvar1d)
        print(unusedvar1d)
```

This section of code is supposed to 1) create a labeled frame where values will be entered, 2) create an entry box for an integer value of the first known variable and a button to confirm the value and create the next entry box, 3) create the next entry box when the button is pressed, 4) create another button to confirm the 2nd value and create the next entry box, 5) create a third entry box when button is pressed, and create another button to run the function calculate1d(), which is currently a placeholder to see if the program returns the correct values.

However, it doesn't work. The code as it is now stops after creating the entry box for the first value and creating the button to confirm and create the 2nd entry box and button. With this code, there is no point where I actually see what value is returned for the entry boxes. However I tried putting putting putting `print(known1d1entryvar.get())` at the start of `getvalue2()` to see what value it was returning, and no matter what value I entered, it returned 0. Furthermore, it printed the value, 0, when I pressed the button(not shown) that calls the `getvalues_1dk()` function, not when I wanted it to, after entering a number in the first entry box and pressing the first button.

Please help me out here. I've been stuck on this for about two days now and I've tried everything I can think of.

EDIT: If necessary, I can post my entire source code on a paste website. Just ask if necessary.

Comment: You don't need to post the entire source code. Just a small working example program with the same problem ... if its possible

Comment: @VRage If I knew what the problem was well enough to recreate it, I would. But I will try. Honestly though, I'm at a loss here. I only started learning how to use Tkinter recently and I'm completely at a loss as for why it doesn't work and how to fix it. As I said though, I'll make an attempt.

Comment: well, you can post the entire code if you want. But without a working example its hard to debug

Comment: Start with one Entry-Label group and get it working before adding more.  Possibly is a scope issue.

Comment: The simple solution is to start with broken code. Keep removing lines while the code continues to exhibit the same symptoms. Eventually you'll find a block of lines that are required to make the program fail. Include just those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ttk entry widgets are more susceptible to garbage collection than the tk entry wigets. You're using local variables for your `IntVar`s. You need to make sure those don't get garbage collected. Even better, just don't use them at all.

Most of the time, the use of `StringVar` and/or `IntVar` is completely unnecessary with `Entry` widgets. You can put values in and get values out of the widgets without them. They merely add an extra object that has to be maintained without giving any real benefit. The only time they are useful is if you use the same variable for more than one widget, or put traces on the variables.